# How to cache content displayed by AJAX call in asp classic

Tags: html, ajax, email, asp-classic, vbscript

How do I cache the content of the website displayed without having to do another ajax call to a function if the user presses back button on a browser?

I don't think I made much sense with my question, so here's more detailed info: In our webmail server, whenever the user clicks on the inbox button, it takes them to another page displaying the subjects of the newly received mail and previously stored mail. (RetrieveNewMessages and ReadMailFolderContents). When the user has a lot of mails either incoming or previously stored, these operations can take a long time to process, so I'd like these functions to run only when the user enters the inbox page for the first time. When the user clicks on a subject to display the mail content and press back to return to the inbox page, these functions are ran again, causing a lot of delay for viewing the mail.

The page initially loads a loading screen, makes an ajax call to the server and when the server is done processing the two functions, it then displays the content stored in a string array.

Here's more or less a skeleton code of what it looks like at the moment:

### Main Sub

```
<%sub main()%>
    <div id="loading" align="center">
        <img src="mail_loading.gif" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
        Retrieving your mails...
    </div> 
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            ajaxed.callback('do', 'mail_listing', null,
            function(t) {
                $('loading').hide();
            });
        };
    </script>
    <div id="mail_listing"></div>
<%end sub>
```

### Sub pagePart_do() (Ajax Call)

```
<%
Sub pagePart_do()

'Gets new mails from pop3 server
Call RetrieveNewMessages(mailbox,uniqueIDTxtFilePath)

retrievedMailContentArray = ReadMailFolderContents(mailDirName,uniqueIDTxtFilePath,flag)

...Run the for loop on retrievedMailContentArray and format it in HTML
%>
```

So in essence, I'd like the html content displayed by pagePart_do() to be cached when the user presses back button to return to the inbox page.

The server is running on ASP Classic and uses [ajaxed](http://www.ajaxed.org/) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably lots of options to solve this.
One option would be to use HTML5 and Web Storage. Web storage is supported in almost all current browsers and allows for persisting up to 5MB of data. Web Browsers expose Web Storage through the localStorage object in JavaScript. One easy way to determine whether a Web Browser can support Web Storage is to execute this JavaScript code:

```js
var webStorageSupported = ('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null;
```

To populate web storage:

```js
localStorage.setItem('name', 'arman');
```

To get the value:

```js
var value = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Comment: Right to the spot. And I thought I was going to agonize myself by caching the ajax content on the server side somehow. Thank you.